# Adding new columns to RDLC, existing columns overlapped

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I have an RDLC report, in which I need to add two new columns between other columns.
When I add a new column and run the report, the new column does not show in the report, even though the visibility of column is true.

I found that whenever I create a column its Z-Index is 0, while all other columns and textboxes have some value for Z-Index.

What is the cause of this? Why do newly added columns show problems in rendering, as compared to existing columns?

Comment: Z-Index shouldn't matter unless you're overlapping things.

Comment: In any case, we'll need more information, a way to reproduce this, some info on what you've tried and found during debugging, perhaps some screenshots even. Without that it's a guessing game for us...

Comment: Are you certain you are running the updated version of the report?. You might still be viewing the old report in your running application.

Comment: Ok Jereon, i did not found as such, do not have much idea about RDLC, i used to add columns in RDL like this only, but here is whenever i add a new column in between, it does not show when run report.

Comment: I did a small trick also, i deleted all columns at the right of the column where i need to add new one, and added again all those, but no luck, 
i just can see, whenever i add a new item, its Z index is 0 but already added items are having a valid Z index.
how to add a new column to RDLC, please just tell me any other way..

Comment: @SQL.NETWarrior : Yes i am sure, i am runnning updated one, i build it again also.